# Why does Vivaldi (and supposedly Chrome) add random stuff to my HTML document when inspecting it?

Tags: google-chrome, vivaldi

My HTML document has this:

```
<html lang="en">
```

In Vivaldi's DOM tree, I instead see this:

```
<html lang="en" class=" auvavsske idc0_338">
```

What's with this random added gibberish? And why did it add a space before the class value? And is this the same in Chrome, or unique in Vivaldi? What's the deal?

Comment: Probably an extension. Maybe some adblocker? // The space is easy to explain though: `element.className += " mystuff"`—works with empty and non-empty *class* attributes.

Comment: @DanielB Now that you say it, it's probably uBlock Origin, then.

Comment: Actually, I just tried with uBlock Origin turned off, and it's still there... I have no other extension other than "I don't care about cookies".

Comment: Try to find `auvavsske` and `idc0_338`. They should be defined in some included CSS file.

Comment: @harrymc Certainly not in any of my CSS files, and those are the only ones included on my pages...

Comment: Complete guess, but [Vivaldi apparently comes with a built-in translation feature](https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/tools/translate-web-pages/). Since this is being added after `lang="en"`, perhaps this class serves as some sort of identifier to help Vivaldi with those (potential) translations.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found the solution.

https://www.i-dont-care-about-cookies.eu/

This little plugin adds extra classes to the HTML tag of your webpage if you have it installed.